# Validations for CSV fields importing to MySQL

Tags: php, validation, csv

I use these codes which import CSV contents into MySQL Database.

```
<?php
    $databasehost = "localhost";
    $databasename = "test";
    $databasetable = "sample";
    $databaseusername ="test";
    $databasepassword = "";
    $fieldseparator = ",";
    $lineseparator = "\n";
    $csvfile = "filename.csv";
    $addauto = 0;
    $save = 1;
    $outputfile = "output.sql";


    if(!file_exists($csvfile)) {
    echo "File not found. Make sure you specified the correct path.\n";
    exit;
    }

    $file = fopen($csvfile,"r");

    if(!$file) {
    echo "Error opening data file.\n";
    exit;
    }

    $size = filesize($csvfile);

    if(!$size) {
    echo "File is empty.\n";
    exit;
    }

    $csvcontent = fread($file,$size);

    fclose($file);

    $con = @mysql_connect($databasehost,$databaseusername,$databasepassword) or die(mysql_error());
    @mysql_select_db($databasename) or die(mysql_error());

    $lines = 0;
    $queries = "";
    $linearray = array();

    foreach(split($lineseparator,$csvcontent) as $line) {

    $lines++;

    $line = trim($line," \t");

    $line = str_replace("\r","",$line);

    $line = str_replace("'","\'",$line);

    $linearray = explode($fieldseparator,$line);

    $linemysql = implode("','",$linearray);

    if($addauto)
            $query = "insert into $databasetable values('','$linemysql');";
    else
    $query = "insert into $databasetable values('$linemysql');";

    $queries .= $query . "\n";

    @mysql_query($query);
    }

    @mysql_close($con);

    if($save) {

    if(!is_writable($outputfile)) {
    echo "File is not writable, check permissions.\n";
    }

else {
    $file2 = fopen($outputfile,"w");

    if(!$file2) {
        echo "Error writing to the output file.\n";
    }
    else {
        fwrite($file2,$queries);
        fclose($file2);
    }
    }

    }

    echo "Found a total of $lines records in this csv file.\n";
?>
```

But i wish to do validations for some of the fields in the csv file.
For example, the second field is an email and i wish to check that the string contains "@".
May i know how/where to add in the codes for such validations?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you don't know where to add these validations?

Comment: Exactyl why are you doing your own csv parsing for reading? PHP has `fgetcsv()` which does the reading/splitting for you

Comment: I'm just a beginner in programming and php.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a regular expression:

```
$lines++;
$line = trim($line," \t");
$line = str_replace("\r","",$line);
$line = str_replace("'","\'",$line);
$linearray = explode($fieldseparator,$line);
//add code for checking email string
if (preg_match("/\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*/", $linearray[1]) === 0) {
//not a email string 
    conitnue;
}
$linemysql = implode("','",$linearray);
```

Comment: preg_match("/\w+([-+.]\w+)@\w+([-.]\w+).\w+([-.]\w+)*/" is the code that checks whether its an email?

Answer (score 0):

Using the built-in function [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php), [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) and the MySQL function [`LOAD DATA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html):

```
$handle = fopen("test.csv", "r");
$continue = true;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE && $continue) {
    // check for valid email (presuming it's in column 1)
    $continue = filter_var($data[0], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}
fclose($handle);

if($continue){
    // using LOAD DATA will be a lot quicker than individual queries!
    $query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '/full/path/to/test.csv'";
}
```